# How can I make a roman numeral list in Markdown?

Tags: list, markdown, roman-numerals

How do I create a **roman numeral list** in Markdown?

Like this...

i)   Higher per acre field of sugarcane.
ii)  Higher sucrose content of sugarcane.
iii) Lower Labor cost.
iv)  Longer crushing period.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Roman numeral lists are **not supported** in pure Markdown.

You can use CSS to define a roman numeral list with lowercase letters, although it will look slightly different:

```
list-style-type:lower-roman;
```

**Result:**

```
  i.  Lorem ipsum  
 ii.  Dolor sit amet  
iii.  Foobar
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me in Jupyter-lab

Answer (score 8):

### Pandoc Supports Roman Numerals for Ordered Lists

The original Markdown doesn't support Roman numerals, and currently (as of version 0.28) neither does [CommonMark](http://spec.commonmark.org/). However, some Markdown flavors and processors *do* support them, either natively or with certain extensions enabled.

[Pandoc](https://pandoc.org) allows you to use two spaces after a letter or Roman numeral to indicate such a list. For example:

```
I.  Foo 
    A.  Bar 
    B.  Baz 
II.  Quux
```

will render the following HTML:

```
<ol type="I">
<li>Foo
<ol type="A">
<li>Bar</li>
<li>Baz</li>
</ol></li>
<li>Quux</li>
</ol>
```

This specific example doesn't require CSS or non-default extensions, but does require that you render your markup with Pandoc rather than some other processor. If you're using anything else, your mileage will vary.

Comment: Not working for me in Pandoc 2.13, I., II., etc. just rendering as a., b., c.